# How can I download all assets of a Unity project, when getting it from version control?

Tags: unity-game-engine, package, package-managers

Is there a version package manager like `npm, maven, nuget, pip`? I just want my asset store assets to be saved in one way and when I open the project from a different computer everything will be downloaded with ease. Unity has a "`package manager`" but as far as I can understand it just helps you get the packages into the "`Assets`" folder. So, I don't see there is no `package.json` all anything like that what has been downloaded and triggered to download if not found.

I am sure there is a way to do it but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Unity's package manager uses `/Packages/manifest.json` to store it's dependencies as a JSON array. You can just copy-paste the file from project to project to have all those dependencies available from the start. Alternatively, you can just copy the individual entries for certain key packages, and use the defaults for the rest.

Just be sure that the packages are compatible with each Unity version you're going to be using.